# can a web application run properly with ASP. net 4.0 framework in IIS 6?

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-4.0

I am running an application in IIS 6 with ASP .net 4 framework. But the application is not able to send data to the devices connected in network but the same application running in IIS 7 with 4.0 .net Framework then this application is working fine and same features are enable for both IIS (6,7) in systems.

Should I need to change any setting of IIS 6 so that application will work fine?

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with asp-classic (besides absolutely nothing)?

Comment: @Martha if you just type ASP it gets automatically renamed to asp-classic.   Happens quite often. I will retag

Comment: Parul, are you getting any error messages?  If so please edit your question to include those in your question.

Comment: error on page showing on IE